# Safari flex vertical align issue

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I'm trying to align vertically a div inside another div using flex boxes. This code is working on Chrome, IE Edge, Opera and Firefox:

```
.editing-viewport {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But on Safari, the div inside the editing-viewport div does not look completely centred on the Y axis. Looks like there are some extra pixels above the div.

[image]
[image]

Comment: post all of your code please so we have a [mcve]

Comment: Without all relevant code we can't reproduce the problem. So at best we can guess what's wrong. Here's a general guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276